# Multithreading: асинхронный вызов потока

Tags: java, многопоточность

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как вызвать в `java` из одного потока (поток 0) другой поток (поток 1) асинхронно и потом вернуться в поток 0 не используя библиотеки `java.util.concurrent`. (Это вопрос с собеседования, самый сложный).

Comment: Что вообще подразумевается под словами *вызвать поток*?

Вызвать метод в другом потоке и асинхронно получить результат?

--

Тогда можно использовать пару очередей (одну для входных аргументов, а другую для результатов и какую-то (зависит  от задачи) комбинацию wait-notify).

Answer (score 5):

```
// thread 1
 Thread2 t = new Thread2();
 t.start();
 t.join();

// thread 2
// do something
```

у вас несоответствие в вопросе, если вызов асинхронный, то возвращаться в поток 0 нет смысла, потому что выполнение там не блокировалось на время вызова потока 1

Comment: Точно подмечено! А при join, "поток 0" выполняющий этот метод на "потоке 1" будет ждать, пока "поток 1" завершит своё выполнение.

Comment: Ответ неверный.

Comment: @Barmaley, ну так напишите верный :)

Comment: вопрос действительно некорректен - при "вызове" потока мы в него не уходим, так что и возвращаться не придется - мы из потока 0 и не уходили.

Comment: @Barmaley, умник, по поводу `О как! человек который не отличает join() от асинхронности` держи свой неработающий код и никому больше не говори что он правильный http://ideone.com/l4U1i1

Answer (score 1):

Самый простой способ вернуться в основной поток - это в дочернем потоке выкинуть исключение :)), предварительно повесив в основном потоке хэндлер:

```
setUncaughtExceptionHandler(Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler eh)
```

**Update**

Рабочий пример кода. Собирайте, запускайте и убедитесь, что все работает асинхронно работают параллельно 2 потока и через секунду дочерний поток выкидывает исключение и управление возвращается к основному потоку.

Убирайте минус, иначе :)

```
public class Main implements Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Main main=new Main();
    Thread childThread=new ChildThread();
    childThread.start();
    childThread.setUncaughtExceptionHandler(main);
    for(int i=0; i < 100; i ++) {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(100);
            System.out.println("Main thread, loop "+i);
        }
        catch(InterruptedException e) {
            break;
        }
    }
}

public void uncaughtException(Thread t, Throwable e) {
    System.out.println("Caught thread "+t.getClass().getName()+" - we're back in main thread!");
    }
}

class ChildThread extends Thread {

@Override
public void run() {
    int j=0;
    while(true) {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(100);
            System.out.println("Child thread, loop "+j++);
            if(j>=10) {
                throw new RuntimeException("Test!");
            }

        }
        catch(InterruptedException e) {
            break;
        }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: @misha-nesterenko аргументировать можно?

Comment: приведите пример кода

Comment: вобщем-то если обработчик вешать не на главный поток, а на дочерний, то его можно использовать в виде сигнализатора о том что поток завершен. Но это не решает проблему блокировки главного потока на время выполнения дочернего, к тому же использовать исключения для передачи сообщений не самое лучшее что можно сделать, для этого вполне хватит `synchronized`, `wait`, `notify` или `join`. Жду код от вас :)

Comment: @misha-nesterenko смотрите пример кода в апдейте ответа :)

Comment: @Barmaley, если я правильно понимаю ChildThread завершится при j == 10 ?

Comment: @Barmaley, (facepalm). Хоть раз запускалось это? Тут ничего не работает, а то что метод выводит `we're back in main thread!` не означает что он выполняется в `main thread`.

Comment: @misha-nesterenko жесть, без комментариев...

Comment: @Barmaley, вы или тролль или совсем не понимаете работу потоков

Comment: @misha-nesterenko а вы хоть проверяли код то прежде чем так безапелляционно заявлять?